# How to disable connectivity check in offline-first app (Chrome - Android, and Safari iOS)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

I'm building a web app that is offline-first. I'm using redux-offline lib to store my state in IndexedDB. The app works wonderfully on the desktop - I can disconnect from the web, refresh the app and all data will be rehydrated from IndexedDB. However when I try to do the same on Android (or iPhone). The moment I go to airplane mode and try to refresh the app, I get a "You are offline." dinasaur error (in Chrome).

Here's what I have in my manifest file now that is relevant:

```
{
  "short_name": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "start_url": "/events",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "...",
  "display": "standalone",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "...",
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ],
  "icons": [{...}]
}
```

Here's my sw.js:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/dist/bundle.css',
  '/dist/bundle.js',
  '/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2',
  '/assets/fonts/...',
  '/assets/images/...',
  '/assets/images/favicon.ico',
  '/assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
  '/assets/activity_notification.mp3',
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('ServiceWorker: Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

Here's my import of it in index.html:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
   .then(function(registration) { console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope); })
   .catch(function(err) { console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err); });
  }
```

All my static resources including my JavaScript bundles are cached using a service worker. It does work, because I see console outputs from the bundle.

I see that all the data is there in the IndexedDB. It doesn't show up in developer console when I'm seeing the offline dino though. It seems that Android simply prevents me from doing anything if I'm offline.

```
GET ...url... net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED ...url...
Navigated to data:text/html,chromewebdata
```

Is there a way to disable that check? What is the proper way to go about it?

Comment: *"All my static resources including my JavaScript bundles are cached using a service worker."* Does that include your HTML files? Does your service worker handle navigation requests? If you're seeing the offline dino on Android then that implies you don't have a SW that's responding to navigation requests with previously cached HTML. Can you share your service worker setup?

Comment: @JeffPosnick you are right, I forgot the index.html in the SW, will try with that and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: @JeffPosnick adding index.html (the only static html file in my project) to SW did not resolve the issue. Updated the question with SW configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your Web App Manifest's `start_url` is set to `/events`, so that's the URL that will be navigated to whenever you launch your web app from the homescreen on an Android device.

You didn't include your `fetch` event handler, but I'm assuming that it doesn't respond to navigation requests for `/events` with the cached contents of `/`, and you don't have `/events` explicitly added to your cache.

You have a few options, based on whether or not `/` and `/events` represent distinct HTML pages:

- Use `/` instead of `/events` as the `start_url`.
- Add `/events` to your list of URLs to precache, assuming that it's a distinct page from `/`.
- If it's actually the same page (because you're writing a single-page app that responds to all navigations with the same HTML), then storing multiple copies of that page under different URLs isn't really efficient. You should instead write a `fetch` event handler that checks to see if `event.request.mode === 'navigate'`, and if so, always respond with the cached response for `/`.
- Alternatively, use a tool like [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) to generate your service worker for you as part of a build process. It can be configured to maintain your list of assets based on the output of your build, and can [automatically handle all navigations](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#navigatefallback-string) for single-page apps by responding with the cached response for your common HTML.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it is a SPA, so fetch event handler seems like a way to go for me. Gonna try this route...